# How to change incoming call notification size in Nexus 5X

Tags: calls

I use a Nexus 5X Android phone and it is quite good.

The only problem I'm experiencing is that when I get an incoming call, it shows only a ***tiny notification*** at the top of the screen so I can't normally see who is calling (all my previous phones could show a full screen caller).

[image: screenshot]

Can I modify it to have a full screen screen of it without installing any lame dialer or caller id app?

Comment: That tiny caller ID is not customizable. Full screen caller ID is only shown when on home screen or when the phone is idle.

Comment: @MANI I think the image shows the home screen... and I can confirm, that when I am on Home screen, I still get that tiny thing. Only when the phone is locked I get the full screen. This is an obvious stepback from Android 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

This smaller Caller ID banner does appear only when on the home screen and when using an application. I assume this was done so as not to cover the whole screen in case the user is doing something critical or the like.

While on the lock screen, an incoming call will take the whole screen to show Caller ID, presumably because the user wouldn't be doing anything if the phone is locked.

I looked through my devices Phone and Accessibility and other settings, and I was not able to find any way to change this. A third party app would be your best bet.

Using Android 6.0.1 to test.

Comment: Unfortunately, the third party apps are either full of ads or provide themes so lame and ugly that my toddler nephew could draw better. I guess I have to accept that _uncolored, minimalist notification._